# Inserting a surrogate pair into MySQL with an INSERT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, unicode, surrogate-pairs

I'm trying to insert a surrogate pair ('', `\uD852\uDF62`, the same as `U+24B62` from [this example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Examples)) into *MySQL*.

An `INSERT` with an unescaped literal, suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819679):

```
INSERT INTO unicode_test (value) VALUES ('');
-- or
INSERT INTO unicode_test (value) VALUES (_utf8'');
```

fails with

```
Error Code: 1366. Incorrect string value: '\xF0\xA4\xAD\xA2' for column 'value' at row 1
```

(note that `\xF0\xA4\xAD\xA2` isn't even close to the original value of `\uD852\uDF62`).

On the other hand, both

```
INSERT INTO unicode_test (value) VALUES (_utf16'');
```

and

```
INSERT INTO unicode_test (value) VALUES (_utf8mb4'');
```

succeed, but the inserted values are different from the original one.

My database uses the `utf8mb4` character set, so I assume it should handle surrogates transparently.

What is the recommended way of inserting non-BMP characters into *MySQL*?

Comment: `\xF0\xA4\xAD\xA2` is _UTF-8_ expression of  codepoint `U+24b62` (or  `\uD852\uDF62` in _UTF-16_).

Comment: Another reference:  http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=%F0%A4%AD%A2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`, not `utf8` or `utf16`.

See "Best practice" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored
It sounds like you don't have the connection parameter (or `SET NAMES`).

What you tried should have worked:

```
INSERT INTO unicode_test (value) VALUES ('');
```

Another approach is

```
INSERT INTO unicode_test (value) VALUES (UNHEX('F0A4ADA2'));
```